# Number of numbers without a given digit $n$ ($1\leq n \leq 9$)?

Tags: combinatorics

Given a number $m$, say $9874,$ how can I find the number of natural numbers before $9874$ without the number $3$ in it?
I got this question for an interview. I was able to solve the problem for $2$ digits and $3$ digit numbers but wasn't able to come up with a generalized algorithm to solve this problem, where the input ranges from $1 \leq m < 10^{16}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Start by finding the number of such numbers up to $8999$.

Comment: I guess your answer is specific to the number 9874... But how do I write a generalized algorithm when there are arbitrary digits involved? Thanks.

Comment: I was looking for something like this: http://oeis.org/A061217

Comment: If you understand how to do it for $9874$ (and also for numbers that have a $0$, $1$ or $2$), you can generalize...

Answer (score 1):

Proposed that the number of representation:$$a_{15}a_{14}\ ...\ a_{1}a_{0}$$
the given number $n$ and the number of numbers **include** $n$ before $a_ia_{i-1}\ ...\ a_0$ is $S_i$($0 \le i\le 15$).

$$
S_0 = \begin{cases}
1,  & a_0 \ge n \\
0, & a_0 \lt n \\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
S_i = \begin{cases}
a_i * S_{i-1} + 10^i,  & a_i\ge n \\
(a_i+1) * S_{i-1}, & a_i\lt n \\
\end{cases}
\ \ \ \ i>0
$$

The result is $a_{15}a_{14}\ ...\ a_{1}a_{0} - S_{15}$

---

For example find the number of numbers not include 3 before 9874 in your question:
Given the represent 
$$a_{15}=a_{14}=...a_4 = 0,a_3 = 9,a_2 = 8,a_1 = 7,a_0 =4$$
$$n = 3$$
According to the $S_i$ above:
$$S_{15} =  S_{14} = ... = S_3$$
$$S_3 = 9*S_2+10^3$$
$$S_2 = 8*S_1+10^2$$
$$S_1 = 7*S_0+10$$
$$S_0 = 1$$

So $S_{15} = 2124$, answer is 9874 - $S_{15}$